# Django 1.6 - DeprecationWarning: Use the LOCALE_PATHS

Tags: python, django, deprecation-warning

After migrating project from Django 1.4 to 1.6 I've started to see a problem in the console:

`/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py:63: DeprecationWarning: Translations in the project directory aren't supported anymore. Use the LOCALE_PATHS setting instead.`

The message is of course pretty self-explanatory, but still would appreciate if someone can specify what has to be done to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this, you have to define a LOCALE_PATHS tuple/list in your settings, as follows:

```
LOCALE_PATHS = ('/path/to/a/locale/directory/',)  # the tuple can of course stay empty
```

As often, you just have to read the docs: [LOCALE_PATHS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#locale-paths)

Comment: Thank you for help Steve. I am new to Django - both your answer and link are most valuable for me at this point.

Answer (score 1):

This [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-translations) explains how Django performs the lookup for `LOCALE` files.